# Can you put many packages inside a single 'Android Library Project'?

Tags: android

When I create an 'Android Library Project' is it OK to put a whole lot of different libraries in there and create a number of different packages?

If I use just one or two components from the library, will it import all the resources and packages or is it smart enough to only import the referenced resources and packages that are needed?

The alternative is to create a single 'Android Library Project' for each component which I don't want to do if I can help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Android library is just like a standard Java library.  You can have multiple packages in the same library.  However, you have to either include the whole library or none of it.  It is not going to pick and choose classes from the library to include.